# iOS Swift Call Function Only When Particular ViewController Is In Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, dispatch-queue

In my app I am having two view controller `viewcontroller1` and `viewcontroller2`. In `view controller1` I am having one function called `UpdateView()` I need to call this function for every `60 seconds` and I did it using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 60)`. My problem is I want to run this function only when `viewcontroller1` is in foreground, when user moved to `viewcontroller2` I don't want to run this function any more. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with a `Timer`. Inside `viewWillAppear` method start the timer and inside the `viewWillDisappear` stop or pause the timer.

```
var myTimer:Timer!
var myTimeInterval:TimeInterval = 60

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        myTimer = Timer.init(fire: Date(), interval: myTimeInterval, repeats: true, block: { (aTimer) in
            //call the functio you want
            UpdateView()
        })
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        myTimer.invalidate()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stop the timer in viewDidDisappear and start your timer logic in viewDidAppear in the ViewController1.